Visual Studio Plugin to save Github Copilot responses
Basically identical to this browser extension for ChatGPT, except as a Visual Studio Plugin/Addon which deals with Github Copilot output.
One of the disadvantages of Copilot is that you can't even select all text, so you need to copy/paste in many pieces.

It should integrate into Visual Studio 2022
It saves a single chat as a single Markdown file
It formats code as code with the correct language tag
It gets the code references right (like #MainWindow) (these won't be copy/pasted via the clipboard by default)
It gets bullet points and enumerations right
It's free (gratis, open-source preferred)
ideally: It saves formulas as Markdown Inline Math (like $\LaTeX$)
optional: It includes information about the model I was using (like 4/4o/4o-mini/o1)
optional: It includes date and time information when I created the chat.

